# Why named expression is necessary in this Numpy function chain?

Tags: python, numpy, method-chaining

This snippet:

```
a = np.arange(12, 0, -1).reshape(3, 4)
(a := a.flatten()).sort()
print(a)
```

produces

```
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
```

as expected. Without named expression:

```
a = np.arange(12, 0, -1).reshape(3, 4)
a = a.flatten().sort()
print(a)
```

I'm getting `None`. Why is that?

Comment: You are storing the return value of `sort` in `a` in the second case. In the first, `a` is assigned the value of `a.flatten()` before actually sorting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [PEP 572 – Assignment Expressions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics)

> Syntax and semantics
>
> In most contexts where arbitrary Python
> expressions can be used, a named expression can appear. This is of the
> form NAME := expr where expr is any valid Python expression other than
> an unparenthesized tuple, and NAME is an identifier.
>
> **The value of such a named expression is the same as the incorporated
> expression, with the additional side-effect that the target is
> assigned that value**:

So this code,

```
(a := a.flatten()).sort()
print(a)
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
a = a.flatten()
a.sort()
print(a)
```

This means that you are not assigning the result of `sort` anywhere. You are letting `a.sort()` to complete and print `a` later(which will result in expected output)

Remember *`sort` is an in-place operation and it returns `None`*, So in your second code you are assigning return value of `sort`(which is `None`).

```
a = a.flatten().sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

[ndarray.sort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html#numpy.ndarray.sort) performs sorting in-place without returning the value.
In your first example you create `a`, then assign the result of `a.flatten()` to it. After that the `sort` function executes sorting in-place on the array which `a` points to. Then you print `a` not result of `sort()`.

In second example you print the result of `sort` which is None, instead of sorted array `a`.